# how to integrate google Collab code in android studio in a right way?

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

when I am running app in mobile, it does not recognize some images of diseases but its Collab code accuracy is above 90%. we save the Collab model with tensor flow extension (code given below)then import it into android studio and copy its java in android.

is there any problem in this method? why accuracy is not good?

here is the code,

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("VGG19-Final.h5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tfmodel = converter.convert() 
open("Model.tflite", "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

Comment: It's not clear: is the training and test data the same in both locations?

Comment: yes probably...  Training dataset contained more data than testing... I have trained the model with 12000 images while testing and validation dataset has 1200 images in both.   I am accessing these dataset through drive in Collab

Comment: the code I provide above is to save the model with tensor flow extension so I can import it in android studio but accuracy is not coming good!!

Comment: Try a small subset of the testing data in both locations, and share that here. That would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: you mean, I should trained a model with more small number of testing data than previous?    Should I do any change in training dataset or not?

Comment: No... If you have trained the model once, then the results should be the same regardless of where the model is deployed. This leads me to believe that test data in both deployments is different.

Comment: hey @ryanwebjackson thanks for your help. But still I am not getting it what you are trying to say about the testing dataset to improve accuracy!